# Setting dependency's loading location

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I'll start by saying that **I have gone over the multiple topics** on this matter and have not found a solution for my problem.

From my understanding when the cx_oracle module wants to load its dependency's it iterates over the paths in the PATH system environment, and will load the first dependency it finds (regardless of its version/operating system compatibility).

I'm working in an environment in which I can't guarantee that the PATH system variable will not be filled with a directory to an 'old' or incompatible oracle client version, but I do have a new system variable which is guaranteed to 'point' to the correct directory.

Is there any way in which I could force the cx_oracle module to load the library from that location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and should, whenever possible) avoid system package version issues by sandboxing your Python environments with something like [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) or [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv).

If that's not an option for you, you could try manipulating the current session's path.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

It's not something I'd really recommend, but if you can't get around this situation, it might be a last resort possibility.

Answer (score 1):

cx_Oracle 7 has a [change](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes.html#version-7-0-september-2018) on Windows (only) that it will first try to load Oracle client libraries from the same directory that the cx_Oracle module is installed into.  If there is no Oracle client there, then the loading falls back to the OS search path (e.g. PATH).

So, as long as you are OK manually adding Instant Client to the Python directories, you will get the desired result.

Using an arbitrary directory outside PATH or the cx_Oracle directory isn't supported natively by ODPI-C.

Comment: What is OPDI-C?

Comment: ODPI-C is the data access layer used by cx_Oracle.  It is the layer that loads the Oracle Client library. See the odpi directory in https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle